# ずぽ meaning in ずぽハメ

Tags: translation, meaning

I came across this term while reading doujinshis & also on R-movies description, but I can't find the meaning of the word.
Is it all right to translate it as ハメ (screwing, xxxx-ing)? Or does it have a more specific meaning?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's ズポ + ハメ. ハメ is "screwing"; it's the stem of the verb [はめる](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%B5%8C%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B). ズポ/ズポッ/ズッポリ/etc is an mimetic/onomatopoeic word that describes how something is deeply stuck in a hole-like or snow-like object. It also describes the friction noise of something being stuck. It is commonly used to describe an aggressive intercourse or its sound. Here are some safer examples:

> - ゴム長靴をずぽっと履く
> - 落とし穴にズポっと填まった
> - 車が雪にずっぽり埋まって動かせない
> - ズポズポと膝まではまりながら雪道を歩く

Comment: Thank you, again, for your great explanation, naruto-san.